# Expression that gets passed a list of items and a way to select a property from one of those items

Tags: c#, expression

This is hard to explain, so i will give a usage example, given the code below:

```
public class ZipCode
{
   ZipCodeId {get;set;}
   Name {get;set;}
}
public class Criteria
{
   List<ZipCode> ZipCodes {get;set;}
}
```

i want to make a extension method that allows me to write the following

```
Criteria crit = new Criteria()
crit.SetVal(c => c.ZipCodes, z => z.ZipCodeId, "some value passed in here");
```

I can make an extension method with a signature like this:

```
public static void SetVal< T,V,K,Z>(this T crit, Expression< Func< T, V>> selector, Expression< Func< K,Z>> key, string value)
```

But then i have to call it with

```
crit.SetVal<PropertySearchCriterionArea, List<ZipCode>, ZipCode, int>(ac => ac.ZipCodes, z => z.ZipCodeId, "some value here");
```

instead of my wanted version

```
crit.SetVal(c => c.ZipCodes, z => z.ZipCodeId, "some value passed in here");
```

As you can see i need to specify every generic parameter type which i do not want to as it should be infered from the signature of the extension method.

So how should i fix this extension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, a small change in your design should allow a better solution:
Change Criteria to the following:

```
Public Class Criterial<T> { List<T> Values {get; set;} /* add additional properties */ }
```

And then, the method should look like this:

```
static void SetVal<T>(this Criteria<T> crit, Expression<Func<Criteria<T>, object>> selector, Expression<Func<T, object>> key, string value)
```

Which ultimately will allow the following code:

```
Criteria<ZipCode> c = new Criteria<ZipCode>();
c.SetVal(x => x.Values, y => y.ZipCodeId, "some value passed in here");
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot change the Criteria object, and it also contains 20+ other collections, the example was simplified, which i should probably have stated in the original question.

Comment: I need some more information to offer a better solution, The question is - does the result of the selector must be the same as the type that key is a property of?
e.g: in your example you use c.ZipCodes for the selected(which returns a List<ZipCode>) - do you want the key to be a property of ZipCode?

Comment: Then you could do something like that:  
`public static void SetVal<T, S>(this T crit, Expression<Func<T, List<S>>> selector, Expression<Func<S, object>> key, string value)`  
(or change the List<S> to ICollection<S>)  
And you can call it like this:  
`c.SetVal<Criteria, ZipCode>(x=>x.ZipCodes,y=>y.ZipCodeId, "test");`

Answer (score 0):

Is you mean like it? ↓

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.SetVal<Criteria, List<ZipCode> , ZipCode , string>(c => c.ZipCodes, z => z.ZipCodeId, "some value passed in here");
    }
}

public class ZipCode
{
   public string ZipCodeId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}

}

public class Criteria
{
  public List<ZipCode> ZipCodes {get;set;}

}

public static class fordynamic
{
    public static void SetVal<T, V, K, Z>(this T crit, Expression<Func<T, V>> selector, Expression<Func<K, Z>> key, string value)
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand this answer, the example in Main looks exactly like the version i would like to avoid, i would like the short version i wrote about in the question